# Excel: Subtracting a number to always match the total

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I want a function that automatically subtracts the current number to match the total.

For example:

I have $54,721.96 total and need my result to be $10,000. I need the formula to find the number that will equal $10,000 (so for this instant "$44,721")

visual example:https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NExT.png

result example:https://i.stack.imgur.com/gazsK.png

Comment: It is very basic. Just minus your result from your input value.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem,
you just have to insert a function in another cell that subtracts the result from the total.

[image: Click to see visual representation]

function used in the cell B2 is **=A2-C2**
Hope this helps you :o